# Detect the actual content in a web page (ignore header, footer, navigation etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

Looking for a way (client-side or server-side) to detect the actual content part of a web page and remove its header, footer & navigation. Something similar to the way the Amazon's "Send to Kindle" add-on for Firefox works. The solution can be either client-side (JavaScript) or server-side.
I understand that it can't be a 100% reliable solution but I was wondering if there's a library/algorithm somebody already used for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Either check which `<div>` tag has the most content (really unreliable) or make a list of all class names/ ids that are used by major sites to mark their main content-markup and save them in a database. you should be able to do with a couple thousand rows and then parse the pages using DOM to check with class name is available.

This might not be the fastest solution, but you could speed it up, if you map certain sites, you know which class names they use.

**EDIT:**
You will still have to refine your algorithm. For example:

- how do you handle multiple of those stored class names being present
- what do you do, if none is present (show the whole page?, Show only the biggest div?

Comment: I've tried the div solution and it really is unreliable. Storing the class names in the database sounds like a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are still some things to be decided. Multiple class names can be solved with nested css rules. If none is present the system will get the biggest div (also, due to the nature of the application this can also be manually fixed).